# Create app notification with react native

Tags: react-native

I everyone.
It's possibile create a info popup in react native app, such as android chronometer?  [image]

I tried to search online, but the truth is, I don't know what to look for. Could you tell me what to orient me on or give me some advice?
thanks in advance to those who will answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use notifee https://notifee.app/react-native
i'm not sure what u want to achieve here but i guess u want to make a like stopwatch app with notification...

https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/timers